# toMap error in mapping a Data Set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm having an error

```
 error: Cannot prove that (Int, String, String, String, String, Double, String) <:< (T, U).
           }.collect.toMap
```

when executing my application having the following code snippet.

```
val trains = sparkEnvironment.sc.textFile(dataDirectoryPath + "/trains.csv").map { line =>
      val fields = line.split(",")
      // format: (trainID,trainName,departure,arrival,cost,trainClass)
      (fields(0).toInt, fields(1),fields(2),fields(3),fields(4).toDouble,fields(5))
    }.collect.toMap
```

What could be the cause and can anyone please suggest a solution ?

Comment: Map is in the form of key-value pairs, try `}.keyBy(_._1).collectAsMap`

Comment: This worked out ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do `toMap` on `Seq`, you show have a Seq of `Tuple2`. ScalaDoc of toMap states :

> This method is unavailable unless the elements are members of Tuple2,
>   each ((T, U)) becoming a key-value pair in the map

So you should do:

```
val trains = sparkEnvironment.sc.textFile(dataDirectoryPath + "/trains.csv").map { line =>
      val fields = line.split(",")
      // format: (trainID,trainName,departure,arrival,cost,trainClass)
      (fields(0).toInt, // first element of Tuple2 -> "key"
       (fields(1),fields(2),fields(3),fields(4).toDouble,fields(5)) // 2nd element of Tuple2 -> "value"
      )
        }.collect.toMap
```

such that your map-statwment returns `RDD[(Int, (String, String, String, String, Double, String))]`